# Reshaping OpenCV Mat fails

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I am unable to reshape my `cv::Mat`.

Here is my code.

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>



int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Start\n";
    cv::Mat eigenvectors = (cv::Mat_<float>(2,2) << 4, 3, 2, 1);
    std::cout << "eigenvectors shape " << eigenvectors.size() << std::endl;
    cv::Mat reshaped = eigenvectors.reshape(4, 1);
    std::cout << reshaped.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << reshaped << std::endl;
}
```

Here is the result.

```
Start
eigenvectors shape [2 x 2]
[1 x 1]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Why is my program claiming to have a 1x1 matrix, but holding the values for a 4x1 matrix? It is only doing this for this dimension.

When I expand my code to include these tests.

```
reshaped = eigenvectors.reshape(1, 4);
std::cout << reshaped.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << reshaped << std::endl;
reshaped = eigenvectors.reshape(2, 2);
std::cout << reshaped.size() << std::
```

I get normal results.

```
[1 x 4]
[4; 3; 2; 1]
[1 x 2]
[4, 3; 2, 1]
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

To improve the Google relevance of this result, another symptom I was having is that as a result of my "reshaping", I was also losing the type of my `Mat`.

Comment: That's weird: your first code snippet worked fine for me. Are you sure that you are passing (1, 4) to `reshape` there and not just (4)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that you fully understand the effect from `reshape()` and the meaning of the parameters you pass to the method. Here's [the article](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=reshape#mat-reshape) from OpenCV documentation on it:

`Mat Mat::reshape(int cn, int rows=0) const`

> ```
> Parameters:   
>
>     cn – New number of channels. If the parameter is 0, the number of channels remains the same.
>     rows – New number of rows. If the parameter is 0, the number of rows remains the same.
> ```

So, at your first code snippet you initialised `eigenvectors` by four elements: 4, 3, 2, 1. `reshape()` creates another matrix of given size parameters for these elements.

`cv::Mat reshaped = eigenvectors.reshape(4, 1);` - here you go, you get the `[1x1]` 4-channel matrix. All the elements are stored in the single 4-channel element of the `reshaped` matrix just like the output says. To create the matrix with wished number of rows and columns set the number of channels and columns accordingly. For example, if there is a 1-channel matix of `[4x4]` size and you wish it to have 2 rows and 8 columns, you just call `reshape(1,2)`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I'm clearly approaching this from the wrong perspective. When I did `reshape(4,1)`, I wanted a matrix with four columns, not four "channels" (my understanding of channels is that they are like the things that combine to make a colour, like red, blue, green, so it makes sense what "size" is returning). Is there some way to specify this with OpenCV or is this the only way that it is implemented?

Comment: Just in case it isn't clear in the solution (I certainly missed it while going over it). My mistake was getting "channels" confused with columns. I fixed my problem by passing in `cn=1` and passing in the row number desired.

Answer (score 1):

The confunsion to most people is, the opencv reshape() function is different to Matlab's reshape, in matlab you manually provide both new numOfRows and numOfCols. With openCV you just provide the new image dimension(number of channels) as the first parameter and then the number of rows as the second parameter.

Open CV automatically figures out the number of new columns for you.